# Installing Pygame on Mac 10.11.6

Tags: macos, python, terminal.app

As the title suggests I am having trouble installing pygame on my Mac. I've tried a lot different solutions. Such as using the steps in Python Crash Course to looking on stack overflow.

I've tried:

- https://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/
- https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-WhAS6qzsU

and I receive error in  pip no matter which technique I use.

In the IDE i'm using which is spyder I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You see the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

because the Python version you are running in your IDE cannot detect te `pygame` module you installed.

### Homebrew Python

A clean way to install and use Python packages on MacOS is to

1. Install Homebrew  - https://brew.sh/
2. Install Python using Homebrew

   `brew install python`
3. In your IDE, set Python's Site-Packages with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, for example for Python 3.7.x, set it to `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You can read the instructions on https://brew.sh/ . Or watch a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SELYgZvAZbU